# ionic v3: Scan a number or text through camera

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ocr

I have tested both card.io and also I have already tried Tesseract.js.
card.io works for cards. But I want to read a number printed on a page.
Tesseract.js isn’t performing well with ionic. Can’t detect most of the numbers and letters.
Can anyone help me with it?
Here is my Tresseract.js cam scanner demo:
https://github.com/anuragbhattacharjee/camscanner-seed

Comment: m having the same issue. U found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ocrad.js` in your ionic application. It is much easy to use. [here](https://github.com/matiastucci/ionic-ocr-example) is the sample application you can download and test.